# How to implement horizontal scrolling in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, css

I am trying to implement horizontal scrolling in Wordpress, but when the size of contents increases my page scrolls vertically. How to fix the problem?

```
// div class to restrict the page maximum height
.container-mine{
    max-height: 620px;
    text-align: center;
    transition:transform 0.4s ease;
}
```

Comment: are you using wrapping your elements in any container div?

Comment: no i am not using wrapping,
my question may not describe completely what i am trying to do but i need to make a theme which has horizontal scrolling, but when i increase the content of any page it goes vertical i need to restrict my page from vertical scroll.